# Django Error ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: python, django

Can't get past this error for a while now, checked all the related topics and everyone had a typo/syntax problem. I have checked everything and the code looks fine and I really can't tell what could be the problem, if anyone sees the issue pls help. Below I'll place my code and the error.

I created a form so I can add a new subject via a button which I call inside my view and render in a template, very simple.

TRACEBACK

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/addsubj/

Django Version: 3.1.5
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'App',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\django\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\django\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\django\project\project\App\decorations.py", line 7, in wrap
    return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\django\project\project\App\views.py", line 40, in add_subject_view
    newsubj = AddSubjectForm()
  File "C:\Users\D\Documents\django\project\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 287, in __init__
    raise ValueError('ModelForm has no model class specified.')

Exception Type: ValueError at /addsubj/
Exception Value: ModelForm has no model class specified.
```

MY FORMS.PY

```
from django.forms import ModelForm from django import forms from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm from .models import MyUser, Subject

 class AddSubjectForm(ModelForm):
        class meta:
            model = Subject
            fields = ['ime', 'kod', 'program', 'bodovi', 'sem_redovni', 'sem_izvanredni', 'izborni']
```

MY VIEW (everything needed is imported in the original file)

```
@mentor_required
    def add_subject_view(request):
           if request.method == 'GET':
               newsubj = AddSubjectForm()
               return render(request, 'add_subject.html', {'subform':newsubj})
           elif request.method == 'POST':
               newsubj = AddSubjectForm(request.POST)
               if newsubj.is_valid():
                   newsubj.save()
                   return redirect('subject_list')
               else:
                   return render (request, 'add_subject.html', {'subform':newsubj})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi brother Mudassar here,

So I had gone through your code and code is right only typing mistake has been made

You had written class meta in small it should be in capital i.e. **Meta** this is only typo error

Your code should look like this...

```
class AddSubjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = ['ime', 'kod', 'program', 'bodovi', 'sem_redovni', 'sem_izvanredni', 'izborni']
```

And also keep in mind that if you are not using all fields of model then only you should specified otherwise type this in fields...

```
class AddSubjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = '__all__'
```

Good Luck

Comment: Well this embarrassing after I checked for every typo there is but guess that is what happens when you stare into the same code for days. :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, it should be `Meta` and not `meta`.